# Call a non exported function from a native C++ dll in C#

Tags: c#, winapi, dll, reverse-engineering, dllexport

I am trying to call a non exported function from a native C++ DLL into a C# program.

I have the function signature, which is of type `typedef void (_cdecl* TfFunc)(int, unsigned char** data)`

The dll is in "A.dll", at offset 0x00003e89d.

In C++ I'd do this :

```
int handle = LoadLibrary("A.dll");
TfFunc func = (TfFunc)((handle) + 0x00003e89d);

func(1, null);
```

However despite searching extensively, I can't find a way to do such a thing in C#

Answer (score 0):

I could solve it with that :

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private delegate void Func(int a1, out IntPtr a2);

IntPtr handle = LoadLibrary("A.dll");
Func f = Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer<Func>(new IntPtr(handle + 0x00003e89d));

IntPtr a2 = IntPtr.Zero;
f(1, out a2);
```

Works as expected

Comment: This code doesn't compile because a2 is an out param